# Strange issue with UDL2.0 (notepad++) regarding numbers at the end of strings

Tags: notepad++, xml, lua

I'm currently at the tail end of writing some custom syntax highlighting for a language that is a mixture of lua and xml (don't ask). As it's lua contained within xml nodes, lua code is required to be within quotes, so I set " as delimiters, and nested all the lua-related keywords and delimiters within the " delimiter.

This works perfectly fine, except for when I nest numbers, which causes numbers at the end of variable names to for some reason be highlighted as numbers, despite this not being the case outside of the quotes. Why are numbers at the end of strings (e.g. foo23) suddenly treated as numbers when nested?

Note: Numbers in the middle of strings are not highlighted, so foo23f appears normally.

Answer (score 0):

[I found a solution](https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331753/thread/03d289c9/#6b40/fc3b) on the notepad++ discussion forum:

> I managed to get around this by adding all my numbers as a keyword in prefix mode.
>   And then only nest the keyword instead of numbers in my () delimiter.
>   I thought it might potentially be nice to have an option to force numbers to require a preceding whitespace to highlight (excluding the specified prefixes of course).
>   But that may not make any sense.

This worked like a charm.